# visual studio building exe to incorrect directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, msbuild

I have a project solution that contains multiple solution folders and projects under it.  when i try to build the lone winform project in the solution (specified path in the project settings are Debug/ for the debug config).  For some reason, vs2010 will build to my Solution root dir/Debug and not to the project root dir/Debug.

This is the dir structure

MyProgram
  ->Globals (Solution Folder, and physical folder)
      -> some dll prog
      -> some dll prog
  ->Front End (Solution Folder, and physical folder)
      -> winform prog

does anyone know why?  I have tried to put the entire path to where the exe should go, but that doesn't solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's the default. The final outputs end up in the toplevel, so if you build DLLs and executables that require them, they will work from this directory.

Comment: If i say that isn't the answer i wanted to hear, will that change anything?

Comment: There are two configuration settings, "Output Directory" for the final products, and "Intermediate Directory" for object files; both are interpreted relative to the project directory, and typically the Output directory starts with `$(SolutionDir)`.

Comment: It turns out that the project file had some lingering changes from when i restructured my solution.  I don't think the locations are set up properly due to the changes made when this was a standalone project.  Thanks.